# Shifting by a number is different than shifting by a variable

Tags: c, byte-shifting

I have the following c code:

```
int foo = 0;
printf("output1: %08x\n", (~0x0) << (~0));
printf("output2: %08x", (~0x0) << (~foo));
```

which prints out:

```
output1: ffffffff
output2: 80000000
```

Why does shifting by the same number produce a different result?

Comment: You are shifting *signed* values. By *signed* amounts. IIRC the latter is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Both of them are undefined behaviour; the results you get are arbitrary.  You can only shift by 0 to one less than the number of bits in the type.  See [C11 §6.7.5 Bitwise shift operators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: a signed shift isn't specifically a problem; a negative shift is, and `~0` is negative (usually treated as `-1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your snippet is an orgy in undefined behavior.

- `0x0` literals as well as variables of type `int` are *signed*, meaning they can get negative values. `~0` is always a negative value.
- Left-shifting a signed int with negative value invokes undefined behavior. (6.5.7/4)
- Attempting to shift more positions than there's room in the left operand invokes undefined behavior. (6.5.7/3)
- Attempting to shift a negative amount of bits invokes undefined behavior. (6.5.7/3)

Therefore anything can happen in this program, including the whole thing crashing and burning. As a rule of thumb, *never* use signed variables together with bitwise operators.

Answer (score 2):

Some compiler may told you the reason:

```
warning: shift count is negative [-Wshift-count-negative]
printf("output1: %08x\n", (~0x0) << (~0));
                                 ^  ~~~~
```

ints are signed and complementing them may produce negative values, and shifting by negative amount is undefined.

For example on my machine it produces:

```
output1: e785ba48
output2: 80000000
```